# Посчитать уже посчитанные циклы/периоды SQL-server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server

Мой запрос:

```
SELECT UserGroupCode,COUNT(UserGroupCode) AS [CountofCycle]
FROM Users.GroupCycles
GROUP BY UserGroupCode;
```

Показывает мне:

```
UserGroupCode CountofCycles
1                   1
4                   1
5                   1
6                   2  (gone into 2nd cycle)
7                   1
8                   1
9                   1
10                  1
11                  1
12                  1
13                  1
14                  1
15                  1
16                  1
17                  1
18                  1
19                  1
```

Когда я пытаюсь посчитать `countofcycle = 1`

```
SELECT Count(t.CountOfCycle) AS 'totalgroups'
FROM 
    (SELECT CreateDate, COUNT(userGroupCode) AS [CountofCycle] 
     FROM Users.GroupCycles 
    GROUP BY CreateDate,UserGroupCode)t
WHERE CountofCycle=1
```

Получаю результат равный `18`, который должен быть `16`, если удалить `CreateDate` из `SELECT` и `GROUP BY` я могу получить точное количество циклов `CountofCycles`, а вот когда изменяю `CountofCycle = 2` или на `> 1` то мне показывает результат `0`.

Что надо сделать, чтобы я смог корректно увидеть результат где `CountofCycles` имеет значение  `> 1`?

Comment: Добавьте соотв. HAVING во внутренний подзапрос.

Comment: А какой набор возвращает ваш подзапрос?

Comment: @vikolyada Я посмотрел ваши предыдущие правки перед тем как отклонять предложенную в этом посте. Объясню причины отклонения: стремление к избыточному форматированию без особых улучшений поста. Возможно, правку в итоге примут (не все читают мету, плюс зависит от состава проверяющих), в любом случае рекомендую в будущем не особо увлекаться форматированием. Часть форматирования была полезна, но в целом -- проще было отклонить, чем отклонить и править. Ничего личного, не воспринимайте негативно.

Comment: @vikolyada приняли. Ну что ж, оставлю ссылку на изучение: [внутристрочное форматирование](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328/) (вы зря цифры повыделяли внутристрочным). В целом, и без такого выделения пост смотрелся хорошо, поэтому речь именно о зряшном украшательстве (не рекомендуется до набора 2к репутации, чтобы разгрузить очередь проверок)

Comment: @AK понял. Спасибо за ссылку, сейчас прочитаю.

Answer (score 3):

Ваш вопрос получается следующим: "почему, выполняя разные запросы, я получаю разные результаты". Логично, что единственно верный ответ - потому что ваши запросы - разные.

когда вы строите запрос так:

```
SELECT UserGroupCode,COUNT(UserGroupCode) AS [CountofCycle]
FROM Users.GroupCycles
GROUP BY UserGroupCode;
```

вы группируете запрос по UserGroupCode, и находите две строки с одинаковыми значениями UserGroupCode.

Когда вы строите запрос (в подзапросе) так:

```
SELECT CreateDate, COUNT(userGroupCode) AS [CountofCycle] 
     FROM Users.GroupCycles 
    GROUP BY CreateDate,UserGroupCode
```

вы группируете запрос сразу по двум полям, и, судя по вашим результатам, у вас нет строк, в которых совпадает **И** UserGroupCode **И** CreateDate одновременно.

Чтобы вы смогли увидеть результат где CountofCycles имеет значение  > 1 (о корректности речи не идет, т.к. результат корректен - просто не соответствует вашим ожиданиям), используйте в подзапросе тот же запрос, что приводите в самом начале.

Answer (score 2):

Определите условие для группы в предложении HAVING(https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms180199.aspx):

```
SELECT UserGroupCode,COUNT(UserGroupCode) AS [CountofCycle]
FROM Users.GroupCycles
GROUP BY UserGroupCode
HAVING COUNT(UserGroupCode) >1
```